# FPDF Put Header + Styling on Auto Page Break Pages

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I'm using `$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true);` to auto break long outputs over multiple pages but I have some styling that I would like to apply to the auto-created pages:

```
// HEADER ------------------------------------------------------------------
$pdf->SetTextColor( $headerColour[0], $headerColour[1], $headerColour[2] );
$pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', '', 17 );
$pdf->Cell( 0, 15, $reportName, 0, 0, 'C' );
$pdf->Ln( 16 );

$pdf->SetLineWidth(7);
$pdf->SetDrawColor($col_r, $col_g, $col_b);
$pdf->Line(0, 0, 0, 300);

$pdf->SetLineWidth(0.5);

$pdf->Line(20, 26, 210-20, 26); 
    $pdf->SetTextColor( 0,0,0 );
    $pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', 'B', 24 );
    $pdf->Cell( 0, 15, 'Results', 0, 0, 'C' );
$pdf->Line(20, 40, 210-20, 40); 
$pdf->Ln( 16 );

$pdf->Write( 6, $file ); // This is about 3 pages long worth of text
```

This adds a header-style block to the top of the page as well as a border on the left hand side all the way down the page. How can I replicate this on each page when the data is too big?

Answer (score 0):

You can create extend class to automatically create the header.
Please check the example at http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto2.htm OR FPDF Tutorial for more information for the others sample.